# Div get bottom position instead of top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html

I don't understand why my div under "Rechercher par" is on the bottom of the row and not on top.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                <h5 class="margin-bottom-null"><span class="widget-title">Rechercher par</span></h5>
                <div class="label-ombrage"></div>
                <div class="div-inline">
                    <div><img src="Content/bullet-empty.png" alt=""><span class="choice-search-item">CRÉEZ UN COMPTE</span></div>
                    <div><img src="Content/bullet-empty.png" alt=""><span class="choice-search-item">VOS CRITÈRES DE RECHERCHES</span></div>
                    <div><img src="Content/bullet-empty.png" alt=""><span class="choice-search-item">INFOS SUR LE SITE</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-separator div-inline pull-right"></div>
            </div>
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4sfkc/1/

```
.label-ombrage {
    width: 60px;
    height: 256px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#cbcbcb;
}

.widget-title {
    color: #659900; /* text color */
    font-family: "Dosis";
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5 {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.bottom-buffer-medium {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.div-inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
.line-separator {
    width: 1px;
    height: 256px;
    /*background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);*/ /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff 0%, #cbcbcb 50%, #fff 100%); /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff 0%, #cbcbcb 50%, #fff 100%); /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff 0%, #cbcbcb 50%, #fff 100%); /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #fff 0%, #cbcbcb 50%, #fff 100%); /* gradient overlay */
}
.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: #cbcbcb 1px solid;
}
.margin-bottom-ligh {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.margin-bottom-null {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.link-utility {
    color: #999; /* text color */
    font-family: "Dosis";
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.choice-search-item {
    color: #999; /* text color */
    font-family: "Dosis";
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.bullet-img {
    height: 31px;
    background: url(../Content/recherche_bullet.png) 0 31px !important;
}
.active-bullet .bullet-img {
    height: 31px;
    background: url(../Content/recherche_bullet.png) 0 0 !important;
}
```

What's I'm looking for is to position the div with content "Vos critères de recherche ..." on the top, the div class="div-inline" in the code upper.

I use Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` on `.div-inline`

Comment: @Jerome2606 Trust me I've been in the same boat. Sometimes the fix is so simple and silly but you just can't see it because you've done hours and hours of coding :)